# How can i add response time in selenium python report

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I have a selenium-python automation test, I am generating HTML/JSON reports using Pytest. I want to add response time in the HTML/JSON report, Is this even possible?

following is my code

test_screenshot.py

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pytest_html
from selenium.common.exceptions import InvalidSessionIdException

    def test_Openurl(setup):
        driver = setup["driver"]
        url = setup["url"]
        try:
            before_time = datetime.now().strftime('%H%M%S%f')  #  Timestamp
            driver.get(url)
            now_time = datetime.now().strftime('%H%M%S%f')  #  Timestamp
            response_time = int(now_time) - int(before_time)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e.message)
    
        assert driver.current_url == URL
        driver.save_screenshot("ss.png")
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        driver.save_screenshot("ss1.png")
        driver.close()
```

Conftest.py

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

    def pytest_addoption(parser):
        parser.addoption("--url", action="store", default="https://google.com/")
    
    @pytest.fixture()
    def setup(pytestconfig):
        s = Service("C:/Users/Yash/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe") 
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
        driver.maximize_window()
        yield {"driver":driver, "url": pytestconfig.getoption("url")}
```

Following is the command i am using to generate reports

> pytest -v -s --json-report --json-report-indent=4 --json-report-file=report/report.json --html=report/report.html test_screenshot.py

Comment: You can [enhance HTML reports](https://pytest-html.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#enhancing-reports) and [modify JSON reports](https://github.com/numirias/pytest-json-report#modifying-the-report).

Comment: @hoefling Thanks this will help me to add response time in HTML report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use some hooks to JSON reports to do this.  something along the line of these in your conftest.py file:

```
@hookimpl(optionalhook=True)
def pytest_json_runtest_metadata(call):
    """
    fixture from the pytest-json-report plugin that will add your info
    """
    if call.when != 'call':
       return {}

    # collect the start and finish times in ISO format for the US/Eastern timezone
    start_iso_dt = timezone('US/Eastern').localize(datetime.fromtimestamp(call.start)).isoformat()
    stop_iso_dt = timezone('US/Eastern').localize(datetime.fromtimestamp(call.stop)).isoformat()
    return {'start': start_iso_dt, 'stop': stop_iso_dt
```

That will land up in your json_report metadata.  (my code needed that US/Eastern timezone, you can obviously adjust accordingly, or just do the difference calculation in this function and `return {'response_time': mydiff}`

Comment: Thank you , it worked, any idea how I can add it to HTML  report ?

Comment: Also, this code snippet is calculating the time difference between start time and end time of test, while I am looking for difference between time  before opening the URL and after opening the url.

Comment: Since this worked for you, would you mind accepting the answer?
your follow up questions are good questions, but very different ones, where each deserves it's own stackoverflow question.  for instance, you'll need to use a different mechanism for the HTML report, and you can add whatever information you want, so to report the time for a URL to load will require that you collect that information and include it as we've done here.

Comment: I am generating two reports HTML as well as json, so wanted to add both in the report. Thanks for suggesting, will create a new question for the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71262238/how-to-calculate-time-to-load-url-in-selenium-python-automation could you please check this