# How to calculate time to load URl in selenium python automation

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a selenium python automation test, which calculates Response time and adds it to JSON report. The problem is the code that I have calculates response time as before opening the URL and after it stops the test. I want to calculate the time it takes to load the URL page.

following is my code

test_screenshot.py

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pytest_html
from selenium.common.exceptions import InvalidSessionIdException

    def test_Openurl(setup):
        driver = setup["driver"]
        url = setup["url"]
        try:
            before_time = datetime.now().strftime('%H%M%S%f')  #  Timestamp
            driver.get(url)
            now_time = datetime.now().strftime('%H%M%S%f')  #  Timestamp
            response_time = int(now_time) - int(before_time)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e.message)
    
        assert driver.current_url == URL
        driver.save_screenshot("ss.png")
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        driver.save_screenshot("ss1.png")
        driver.close()
```

Conftest.py

```
    import pytest

    from selenium import webdriver
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    
        def pytest_addoption(parser):
            parser.addoption("--url", action="store", default="https://google.com/")
        
        @pytest.fixture()
        def setup(pytestconfig):
            s = Service("C:/Users/Yash/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe") 
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
            yield {"driver":driver, "url": pytestconfig.getoption("url")}
        
        @hookimpl(optionalhook=True)
        def pytest_json_runtest_metadata(call):
            """
            fixture from the pytest-json-report plugin that will add your info
            """
            if call.when != 'call':
            return {}

            # collect the start and finish times in ISO format for the US/Eastern timezone
            start_iso_dt =timezone('Asia/Kolkata').localize(datetime.fromtimestamp(call.start))
            stop_iso_dt = timezone('Asia/Kolkata').localize(datetime.fromtimestamp(call.stop))
            response_time = (stop_iso_dt - start_iso_dt).total_seconds()
            return {'response_time': str(response_time)}
```

I am getting confused how i should calculate load time in conftest.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is pass the value of the `response_time` variable to pytest through a fixture so that it's available to
the `pytest_json_modifyreport` hook.

Since I wanted to add multiple timers to an individual test case, my solution to this was to create a new fixture that provides a factory, something like this (though I used a custom object in the factory, I'm guessing/hoping a dictionary like this will work):

```
@fixture(scope='session')
def timings(metadata):
    """
    used to track stopwatch timings taken during a session
    """
    stopwatches = []

    def factory(stopwatch_name, response_time):
        fsw = {'name': stopwatch_name, 'response_time': response_time}
        stopwatches.append(fsw)
        return fsw

    yield factory

    # add our stopwatches to the session's json_report metadata so that we can report it out
    metadata['stopwatches'] = stopwatches
```

your test class uses the fixture, and the test case gets an instance.  something like:

```
@mark.usefixtures('timings')
class TestFuzzyBear:
    ...
    response_time = int(now_time) - int(before_time)
    first_url_response_time = timings('first_resp_time', response_time)
```

now all of your response times are in a list of dictionaries in the json_report metadata's environment attribute.  from within the pytest_json_modifyreport hook:

```
@hookimpl(optionalhook=True)
def pytest_json_modifyreport(json_report):
    ...
    stopwatches = json_report['environment']['stopwatches']
```

and now you can do what you need to do with the information.

[note that I have pasted and manipulated the info here, so it may not work as written, but it should give you a direction to follow.]

Comment: Thank you sir means a lot, I had commented, it probably got deleted.

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 64   Any idea why am I getting this. geckodriver is 0.31.0 and firefox browser version is 100